# OneToMany and ManyToOne : Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions

Tags: java, hibernate

I've 2 different table "Employee" and "Diklat" or we Can call "Activity" They've oneToMany and ManyToOne Relationship.

In scenario of SAVE method, its work fine but when I try to proceed "Delete" from my "Activity" Table who has OneToMany Relationship, It wont work and gave me this kind of error,

> org.hibernate.HibernateException: Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions

This is my "**Employee**".class Table :

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "emp_id")
private Integer emp_id;

@Column(name = "nip")
private String nip;

@Column(name = "nama_pgw")
private String namaPgw;

@Column(name = "pangkat")
private String pangkat;

@Column(name = "golongan")
private String golongan;

@Column(name = "jabatan")
private String jabatan;

@Column(name = "eselon")
private String eselon;

@Column(name = "status")
private String status;

@Column(name = "jam_diklat")
private Long jam_diklat;


@JoinColumn(name = "diklat_id_1", referencedColumnName = "id_diklat")
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private t_diklat diklat_id_1;

 @JoinColumn(name = "diklat_id_2", referencedColumnName = "id_diklat")
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private t_diklat diklat_id_2;
@JoinColumn(name = "diklat_id_3", referencedColumnName = "id_diklat")
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private t_diklat diklat_id_3;
@JoinColumn(name = "diklat_id_4", referencedColumnName = "id_diklat")
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private t_diklat diklat_id_4;
@JoinColumn(name = "diklat_id_5", referencedColumnName = "id_diklat")
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private t_diklat diklat_id_5;
```

This is my **diklat/Activity**.class table :

```
 @Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "id_diklat")
private Integer id_diklat;

@Column(name = "nama_diklat")
private String namaDiklat;


@Column(name = "tgl_start")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date tgl_start;

@Column(name = "tgl_end")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date tgl_end;

@Column(name = "jam_diklat")
private Long jam_diklat;



@Column(name = "keterangan")
private String keterangan;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "diklat_id_1")
private Set<t_employee> itemDiklat_1;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "diklat_id_2")
private Set<t_employee> itemDiklat_2;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "diklat_id_3")
private Set<t_employee> itemDiklat_3;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "diklat_id_4")
private Set<t_employee> itemDiklat_4;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "diklat_id_5")
private Set<t_employee> itemDiklat_5;
```

and this is my **DaoImplement** class

```
  public String delete() {

    diklatT = (t_diklat) (listDiklat.getRowData());
    diklatDao dao = new diklat_Impl();
    dao.remove(diklatT);
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Successful", "Data Pegawai " + diklatT.getNamaDiklat() + " Berhasil Diupdate"));
    context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Check Kembali Kelengkapan Data Pegawai"));

    return "diklat_client";
}
```

and this is my DAO class

```
@Override
public void remove(t_diklat diklat) {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

    try {
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.delete(diklat);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (ArithmeticException ex) {
    session.getTransaction().rollback();
        throw ex;
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, do you have solution @BalusC ??

Answer (score 0):

You load *diklat* object in one Hibernate session and try to remove in other session.

In Hibernate each entity belongs only to one session and you must work with this entity only in this session.

Comment: Thanks, but how I solve it, is there any way to solve it?